# Pasta VS Potatoe - Which is worse, and/or better for you

Tags: nutrition, carbohydrates

My business partner and I are avid fans of choosing good foods. I choose pasta as my carb source, he chooses potatoes.

The questions are:
Is one of these 2 worse for your health then the other?
Is one of these 2 better for your health then the other?

Comment: There's a lot of variables here, what sort of pasta do you eat? Does he load potatoes up? 

If you consider most pasta akin to white bread, here's an interesting read: 

Living on bread & water vs living on potatoes & milk: 

http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/2828/could-i-survive-on-nothing-but-potatoes-and-milk 

http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/191/can-man-live-by-bread-alone

Comment: assume very healthy, were more considered with carbs and what the body does with it. is one a better source of something or worse for you somehow.

Comment: For all products claiming something is "healthy" or good for your health, I'd like a definition of "healthy".

Answer (score 1):

Potatoes have are a great source of many minerals and a healthy option for a carbohydrate.  They may raise your blood sugar rather quickly, but so will your typical pasta. If you eat the skin, that is a decent source of fiber, so that should slow the absorption of the carbs. Potatoes are actually significantly higher in potassium than bananas, go figure.
However, it is hard to say whether or not potatoes or pasta are going to be a benefit to your diet depending on the rest of your food intake. Assuming you are not overindulgent in calories or carbs, then I would suggest potatoes. But, variation is always a great idea, so maybe you can switch to pasta occasionally.

Comment: Please do add some references.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].